# How to Fix Cordova installation error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am installing cordova using NPM (Node.js), but I am getting the below error:

[image]

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: do you have proper network connection? I can see error of network.

Comment: I can also see the same Error , But fact is i am having  4 MBPS connection . So this cannot be the reason....

Comment: can you paste `npm-debug.log` file.

Comment: And are you really not using a proxy to access internet (the fact you have a fast connection doesn't mean it's a direct connection). are you able to ping registry.npm.org from your command line?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a proxy issue , i believe that u have to set the proxy in the npm ,
you could do that by running this

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

port name and company would vary . as accordingly .

Go to `Tools->Internet option->Connection->Lan Setting` in the internet explorer 
in the lan settings look into the proxy server address and port (if any)
Hope this helps.